# Codeigniter create arabic slug with url_title result ??????? in database

Tags: codeigniter, arabic, slug

I am working on an Arabic-French lexicon.

https://lexique-arabe.org

Using the latest version of Codeigniter (3.1.10).

I haven't a problem to save and view Arabic characters, AJAX requests for Arabic characters work fine.

But, I try to create mixed slug for an Arabic-French lexicon.

For example I need to create

lexique-arabe.org/lexique/amour-محبة (this link doesn't exist yet.)

I use url_title to generate the slug

Helper

```
function setSlug($string){
    $string = convert_accented_characters($string);
    return url_title($string, 'dash', true);
}
```

Controller

```
$string = $mot->fr.' '.$mot->ar;
$slug = $this->db_utils_lib->stripAccents(setSlug($string));
```

Result in the database for the field slug :

amour-????????

The ???????? should be the Arabic characters.

If you check the website, you can see that there is no problem with the Arabic characters to save are in the database.

I think there is a problem with config or url_title function

My database config

```
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

Some config

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Patrice

Comment: You should try to find out where the data gets lost, in the db or in the `setSlug` function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database encoding accept arabic.

Using SQL and database management tool. Try create a table with text column.

Try to insert Arabic text into the database.

Make sure the text is stored as Arabic.

Try different database clients to see the Arabic text data. Sometime the data is correct but the client/browser/GUI fails to render the correct encoding.

Or simply the client/browser/GUI is missing the correct font.